# warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale

Tags: locale, language-support, internationalization

I want to switch to French locale. So I tried the below command:

```
myUbundu@myUbundu-desktop:~$ export LC_ALL=fr_FR
```

But I am getting the warning

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (fr_FR)
```

How to set the locale to French? Do I need to install additional packages?

Comment: Related: [How do I fix my locale issue?](https://askubuntu.com/q/162391/78223)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try the following commands

```
sudo locale-gen fr_FR
sudo update-locale LANG=fr_FR
```

Comment: `sudo: locale-gen: command not found` Do I need to install that tool? How?

Comment: @DiAlex without the ':' after sudo

Comment: @infoclogged He pasted the output indicating that he does not have the `locale-gen` installed. What is the package name for `locale-gen` is my question too.

Comment: `sudo apt install locales` should do.

Answer (score 40):

I've had the same issue, and none of the answers worked, except `dpkg-reconfigure locales`. But it is too time consuming to do it this way.
Just uncomment all the locales you need in `/etc/locale.gen` and run `locale-gen`.
Or do it from the command line (as root):

```
echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
echo "fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen
locale-gen
```

Comment: Contrary to the other answer this worked for me as well.

Comment: Contrary to the accepted answer, this also worked for me (Ubuntu 16-04) though I just looked in the locale.gen file and uncommented the locales I wanted.

Comment: Among all the answers (including the accepted one), this is the only one worked for me.

Comment: same, i tried all the others, but this worked, thanks mate for getting the annoying error out

Answer (score 15):

I have fought with this for a week or so.

The most reliable (and easiest too) for me was to edit my profile file with

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

An add this language variables to be set at every login

```
LANG="en_AU.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_AU:en"
```

You need to log out and back in for the change to take effect.

Comment: This also works from the command line, when you only want to change it for a certain time.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing language pack for French, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-fr
```

For any other language, run: `check-language-support -l CODE` to check the supported packages, e.g.

```
$ check-language-support -l fr
firefox-locale-fr gimp-help-fr hunspell-fr language-pack-fr language-pack-gnome-fr thunderbird-locale-fr wfrench
```

Check also: [LC_ALL: cannot change locale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157124/21471).

Answer (score 2):

## UTF-8

Here is the `UTF-8` version of the most voted answer.

I received the following error:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_IE.UTF-8)
```

Issuing the following command sufficed to get rid of this `bash` warning:

```
$ sudo locale-gen en_IE.UTF-8
```

P.S.: The Irish locale `en_IE.UTF-8` provides English language with euro € as a currency.

Comment: This works only if `en_IE.UTF-8` is already specified in`/etc/locale.gen`. But since `locale-gen` does not accept (ignores) arguments you can issue `sudo locale-gen` w/o any arguments as long as your preferred locale is already listed in `/etc/locale.gen`. See @Alek_A answer for a more efficient approach

Answer (score 1):

This system had this problem and none of the other solutions worked. After grepping around, `.xsessionrc` had defined corrupted values. Maybe some program created it and it shouldn't be there? Anyway, corrected to reflect system settings:

```
export LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8
export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=fr_FR.UTF-8
```