# How to get past "cannot change locale" error in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, language-support, locale

My server is hosted by a french provider, which by default set locales to french (quite obviously) when a new system is installed.

From there… Just no way to cleanly change it without getting the following error :

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US:UTF-8)
```

I've been googling for a week and tried many ways to set it cleanly; but it remains ill.

I would be very happy to know if there was a clean, efficient way to set it (as far as I've read, this change remains odd and no working answer has been found).

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon.  If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay to close it, but what has been explained in two lines here http://askubuntu.com/questions/253381/how-to-get-past-cannot-change-locale-error-in-ubuntu-server#comment317073_253381 does not works on my side. So in my opinion it is not a valid answer (anymore… what version of ubuntu are we at ?) @eliah-kagan

Comment: @Ben If I understand you correctly, you're saying you tried both answers [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/114759/warning-setlocale-lc-all-cannot-change-locale) and neither worked for you. Assuming that is the case, please edit your question to include detailed information about what you tried and what happened (not just a link). Then it will be clear this is not a duplicate, and enough information will be present so that someone unfamiliar with its history will be able to see it and post a useful answer. Then I think it will be quite appropriate to reopen this.

Comment: I understand I do not provide enough informations. But the answer shown on your link is clear. I typed sudo locale-gen fr_FR and 
sudo update-locale LANG=fr_FR. it remains the same.