# setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8)

Tags: locale

When I press tab for autocompletion I get this error:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8)
```

I've tried running this:

```
locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
reboot
```

But it doesn't help. Do you know what is missing?

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue?rq=1

Comment: UTF-8 as a locale-name looks wrong.

Comment: Fixed on my ubuntu box by running: apt-get install language-pack-en-base, 
update-locale LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8",
locale-gen (not GB not US)

Comment: My answer is regarding Debian, but I was having this issue and simply ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` according to [Locale - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale)

Comment: This should be the duplicate of: [warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale](http://askubuntu.com/q/114759/78223) or [How to solve LOCALE problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/454260/78223).

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure locales` solved the problem for me :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Fixed it by adding these lines to `~/.bash_profile` on my local machine (OSX).

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Actually, setting both LANG and LC_ALL makes little sense. And you should really take a look at `/etc/default/locale` to fix the issue system-wide.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson On the server it's `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. That file doesn't exist on OSX.

Comment: Missed that you connect remotely. So apparently your local locale settings are exported to the server. In any case, given that LANG is used on the server, setting LANG in ~/.bash_profile ought to be sufficient. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Locale_setting_variables describes the various locale categories.

Comment: I experienced the same problem (locale warning on `tab` for auto-complete) on remote sessions from OS X to Ubuntu. This answer worked for me as well.

Comment: This did not work for ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 6):

You may have some odd setting in `/etc/default/locale`. "UTF-8" is not a complete locale name.