# How to solve LOCALE problem

Tags: 12.04, cloud, locale

I am facing a problem as asked in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue), I have tried the proposed solution but facing the same issue

When I run `locale`,

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

When I run

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

I get this error

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
Generating locales...
en_US.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 177: warning: setlocale: 
LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
/usr/sbin/locale-gen: line 243: 
8925 Killed localedef $no_archive -i $input -c -f $charset $locale_alias
$locale failed
Generation complete.
```

I am running `Ubuntu Cloud Image` on `OpenStack` cloud

Comment: try to run localedef en_US.UTF-8 -i en_US -fUTF-8

Answer (score 61):

The problem is due to [this bug](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/920601). The cloud images only support "en_US.UTF-8" so you have to make sure that the host server (the install of Ubuntu Server which you use to SSH into the cloud install) is configured to use "en_US.UTF-8"

To do this generate the "en_US.UTF-8" on the Ubuntu server install:

```
$ sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.

$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

Use the newly generated locale on the Ubuntu Server install by editing `/etc/default/locale` to contain only this line:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Reboot and then access the cloud install.

**Edit:**

[People with a similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/229512/76766) have had good luck editing (or creating) `/etc/environment` to contain:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

... as well.

Comment: locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX

Comment: Also to fix this issue i had to add to /etc/default/locale the line LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Editing /etc/environment and adding LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. It was because the RAM memory I used to boot the image was not enough.

I used 128 and did not work!

Now I used 512 RAM for my instance and it is working.

Comment: How did you figure out that it was the memory?