# How do I change my locale?

Tags: time, locale, date

I am using **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop version** and i need help regarding formatting of locale. In short I need help on creating a locale that fits my needs as so:

1. date should be given as: Monday, 24th November 2021
2. the time should be given as 13:03:23
3. date and time should be Monday, 24th November 2021
4. numbers should be given as 23,000.00
5. currency should be in US Dollars
6. It will use metric and a4 paper
7. monday is the first day of the week
   Also the top bar should have the time as Mon 24/11/2021 13:03
   Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning: setlocale: LC\_ALL: cannot change locale](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114759/warning-setlocale-lc-all-cannot-change-locale)

Comment: I'm using the Desktop Version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a new system locale](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653008/how-to-create-a-new-system-locale)